Обновлении страницы webpack-dev-server при изменении html файла
Пробую создать сборку gulp , используя webpack-dev-server для отображения изменения при разработке. Но в процессе наткнулся на проблему импорта отдельных компонентов в html на примере @@unclude.
Что бы решить проблему с импорта компонентов нашол плагин FileIncludeWebpackPlugin
new FileIncludeWebpackPlugin({
            source: "src/components/pages",
        }),

но при его использовании при запуске webpack-dev-server страницы автоматически не перезагружает внесённые изменения в html файл
вот так я настраиваю сервер
export function buildDevServer(options) {
    return {
        port: options.port,
        open: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: true,
        static: nodePath.resolve("./build"),
        host: 'local-ip', // localhost
        watchFiles: [
            nodePath.resolve(options.paths.html, "index.html"),
            nodePath.resolve(options.paths.html, "contact.html")
        ],
    };

почему так происходит , и как это можно решить?
}
